# Invalid signatures when running apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gpg

I am trying to run an update, I get a lot of "Hit"'s and "Ign"'s but in the end I get these errors, does anybody know what they mean and how I can fix them?

```
W: GPG error: http://speglar.simnet.is olivia Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>
W: GPG error: http://speglar.simnet.is raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team
```

Comment: Each repository (more or less) has its own key to sign packages. Did you run `apt-key` or a corresponding GUI to install extra keys for these repositories?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, can I run gedit apt-key and add these keys into the file? What are these keys anyway?

Comment: You add a key by running the `apt-key` command (or with an equivalent GUI, for example the interface to add a PPA in the default software manager on Ubuntu does that automatically), you can't edit a file directly. Expand “Technical details about this PPA” then click on “What is this?” after “Signing key” in a [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) for more explanations. The purpose of the signing key is to verify that the package files that you receive are genuine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Gilles explained, most Linux repositories are signed with [GPG encryption keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard). `apt` then uses these keys to ensure the authenticity of the repositories. In order to safely use a repository, you need to add it's keys to the list that `apt` considers trusted.

Each necessary key needs to be downloaded from a [key server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_%28cryptographic%29) which is done with this command (I am using `keyserver.ubuntu.com` but you can use others):

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com KEY_NAME
```

From `man apt-key`:

```
   adv
       Pass advanced options to gpg. With adv --recv-key you can download
       the public key.
```

In your case, `apt` is complaining about keys `3EE67F3D0FF405B2`,`40976EAF437D05B5`,`40976EAF437D05B5` and `5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0`, you can get all three of them by running:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 40976EAF437D05B5 40976EAF437D05B5 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
```

If all goes well you should see various lines of output including:

```
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:               imported: 4  (RSA: 1)
gpg:              unchanged: 0
gpg:         new signatures: 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternate possibility, if your apt-get/aptitude has been found in an unusual state recently, is that its internal lists are damaged and incompatible with the true keys. Cleaning the cache and restarting on fresh basis can help:

```
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists
   sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
   sudo aptitude update
```

(op: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=802156&p=9697234#post9697234 )

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this was a time sync issue.
Sharing the solution for posterity's sake
([original solution](https://hub.tcno.co/windows/wsl/fix-apt-update/))

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

# add the following servers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

#Run this
sudo hwclock -s
```

Comment: What's the relation between DNS servers and `hwclock`?