# linux mint - invalid signature BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 for extra.linuxmint.com repository

Tags: linux-mint, apt, gpg

While trying to run `apt-get update` on `linux mint 17.3` I am getting following error.

```
W: GPG error: http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa Release: The following 
signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux 
Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>
```

I tried adding key `3EE67F3D0FF405B2` as mentioned on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97493/invalid-signatures-when-running-apt-get-update) but the key remains unchanged and there no expired key in the list either.

The content of my official source package list file is as follows

```
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/linuxmint/packages rosa main upstream import 

deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa main

deb http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
```

The mirror site `http://free.nchc.org.tw/linuxmint/packages` and extra repo site `http://extra.linuxmint.com` have identical structure. What is causing the error and how to resolve it?

Also is there alternative mirror for `http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa main`??

Answer (score 2):

Try to  install the keyring:

```
sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated linuxmint-keyring
```

Then:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I get `linuxmint-keyring is already the newest version.0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.`

Comment: Is there alternative mirror for `deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa main`??

Answer (score 1):

Came across this and it's old but for others who find it:
Just want to add that none of this the fixes described above are necessary (with current versions of Ubuntu/Mint at least). All you have to do is change mirrors on the "Software Sources" GUI.
I had the EU one selected, randomly was getting this same error msg detailed in OP After trying so many methods, I discovered all I had to do was change to USA one - fixed.
If that doesn't work keep trying different mirrors until it does.
This isn't an uncommon situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with version 17 Qiana. I slightly adapted the above:

Installed the Keyring (might not be required?):

```
sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated linuxmint-keyring
```

Removed files associated with extra.linuxmint.com from /var/lib/apt/lists:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/extra.linuxmint.com_dists_qiana*
```

Then ran the updates (but not the upgrade):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I reran update manager and it worked without errors.

Note: on checking I found that this process had restored a new set of four extra.linuxmint.com_dist_qiana_.... files all dated 11 Feb 2016 in /var/lib/apt/lists, whereas previously there were only three such files some of which had later date stamps. No doubt someone somewhere knows how this came about ...

Comment: apt update and apt-get update do the same thing, apt-get is just depreciated.